# OpenTLD MatLAB mex error, OpenCV library

Tags: matlab, opencv

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and MatLAB R2016b student version,OpenCV 3.1 installed by following [this tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/).

I downloaded the source code for the OpenTLD tracking algorithm and am trying to run the compile.m file and encounter the following errors

As a side note I have implemented the changes that resolve the issue when looking for the cv.h header file

The defintions were

```
(#include "cv.h")
(#include "highgui.h")
```

and were changed to

```
(#include <opencv/cv.h>)
```

The error I receive when running compile.m

```
Error using mex
/tmp/mex_36621193718999_4249/lk.o: In function `normCrossCorrelation(_IplImage*, _IplImage*, CvPoint2D32f*, CvPoint2D32f*,
int, char*, float*, int, int)':
lk.cpp:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x1b9): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x1d6): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x214): undefined reference to `cvGetRectSubPix'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x227): undefined reference to `cvGetRectSubPix'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x23b): undefined reference to `cvMatchTemplate'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x274): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x27d): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x286): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
/tmp/mex_36621193718999_4249/lk.o: In function `mexFunction':
lk.cpp:(.text+0x323): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x341): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x438): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x455): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x4be): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x4dc): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x553): undefined reference to `cvAlloc'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x565): undefined reference to `cvAlloc'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x578): undefined reference to `cvAlloc'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x613): undefined reference to `cvAlloc'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x61e): undefined reference to `cvAlloc'
/tmp/mex_36621193718999_4249/lk.o:lk.cpp:(.text+0x626): more undefined references to `cvAlloc' follow
/tmp/mex_36621193718999_4249/lk.o: In function `mexFunction':
lk.cpp:(.text+0x6c1): undefined reference to `cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK'
lk.cpp:(.text+0x73e): undefined reference to `cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


Error in compile (line 77)
    eval(['mex lk.cpp -O' include lib]);
```

Comment: My first thought is that (since the OpenTLD project seems to have been unmaintained for several years) you might have been better off installing the native 2.x branch `libopencv-dev` from the repository

Comment: I used the command: sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev,  and re-ran the compile.m file but it returns the same errors. Thanks for your help though. I keep thinking though that something is incorrect with the paths in file, compile.m, as surely the latest OpenCV  library should have these "functions" such as  cvCreateImage?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the provided `compile.m` is hard-wired for a particular version (and location) of OpenCV:

```
if isunix
    disp('Unix');

    include = ' -I/usr/local/include/opencv/ -I/usr/local/include/';
    libpath = '/usr/local/lib/';

    files = dir([libpath 'libopencv*.so.2.2']);
```

I was able to get it to compile and link on 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 with the standard `libopencv-dev` 2.4.9 from the repository by making the following changes:

```
if isunix
    disp('Unix');

    include = ' -I/usr/include/opencv/ -I/usr/include/';
    libpath = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/';

    files = dir([libpath 'libopencv*.so.2.4'])
```

*NB I did not attempt to test the resulting `mexa64` objects*

Comment: It seemed to compile correctly, however, the error:  Undefined function or variable 'lk'.

Error in tldInit (line 20)
lk(0);

Error in tldExample (line 34)
tld = tldInit(opt,[]); % train initial detector and initialize the 'tld' structure

Error in run_TLD (line 42)
[bb,conf] = tldExample(opt);                         is now present. After some research it seems incomplete compiling might be the cause of not being able to locate the lk function?

Comment: And I also encountered the error : Error using mex
Unknown file extension '.4'. It seems after some research this could be due to shared objects.